# The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration error with LocalDB+EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Trying to get the connection working seperately,however It keeps insisting that it can not find the connection.

My config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Tank_Analizor_DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Analizor.csdl|res://*/Analizor.ssdl|res://*/Analizor.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=|DataDirectory|\DB\Tank_Analizor_DB.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Tried changing the path directly to the database file,such as :

```
    <add name="Tank_Analizor_DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Analizor.csdl|res://*/Analizor.ssdl|res://*/Analizor.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=C:\Debug\DB\Tank_Analizor_DB.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

But still no luck,what could be the problem here?

Comment: is your entity model in a different project that the application, or are they both part of the same project (not solution)?

Comment: All in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Update the entity framework connection factory settings. You're connection string pointing to sql server compact but the connection factory is configured for sql server v11.0

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```